# CreateFileMapping with class containing virtual methods

Tags: c++, shared-memory, virtual-functions

I want to create an instance of a class and place it in shared memory so the same instance can be called from multiple processes. However, this class has virtual methods which I think may cause problems as I have read the mapped data can't contain pointers, which would be the case here with the vtable in the class. Will it work?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Noooooooo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kerrek SB commented, you cannot map a class containing virtual methods.  But you can probably make a simple struct or class without virtuals, map that, and then give a pointer to it to another class which does have virtuals and uses the plain struct as its implementation.  Basically, the [Pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

If needed, you can even do something like virtual dispatch yourself by storing a "type" integer in the plain struct, and inspecting it to decide which functions to invoke.